# click() não reconhece botão inserido dinamicamente dentro de tr

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Insiro itens dinamicamente em uma tabela usando a seguintes função:

```
$("#inserir-item").click(function (){
    ...
    $("table#tb-itens tbody" ).append(retorno);
}
```

A variável retorno contém algo como:

```
"<tr id="tr-22-2222" align="center">
    <td>22-2222</td>
    <td align="left">Descrição IV</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" value="22-2222" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
    </td>
</tr>"
```

Logo em seguida, ao clicar no botão (inserido na tabela utilizando a função mecionada) não obtenho retorno.

Função utilizada para interação com o botão:

```
$("table#tb-itens tbody tr button[type=button]").click(function (){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
$(document).on("click", "table#tb-itens tbody tr button[type=button]", function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Dessa forma, usando [eventos delegados](http://api.jquery.com/on/), existe a vantagem de poderem processar eventos de elementos descendentes adicionados ao documento posteriormente.

Comment: Olá Lucas Costa, poderia complementar a resposta explicando o porquê?

Comment: Claro, resposta editada @luccasrodrigo